# CPU usage remains at 13% even after I quit the kernel

Tags: system-performance

I use *Mathematica* 10.0.0, and after I run it for a while (a few simple commands for example) the CPU usage (Mathematica.exe) remains at 13% even after the calculations are over. I quit the kernel but the program continues to consume resources until I close the program entirely.

Is it a bug? How can I suppress such behavior?

Comment: Mathematica.exe is the front end process, not the kernel (which is MathKernel.exe). It does sound like a bug though - does the CPU usage continue even after all notebooks are closed?

Comment: You haven't given enough information about your work environment for anyone to be able to help. What OS and processor are you using? How did you quit "the" kernel? Does it happen repeatedly? What is the CPU usage with at the start of a new session with no notebook? Does the problem happen when you start _Mathematica_ by double-clicking on notebook icon? etc., etc.

Comment: @Simon Mathematica.exe uses 13-14% even after I close all notebooks.

Comment: @m_goldberg  $Version: 10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit). Quit kernel means to go to Evaluation->Quit kernel->local

Comment: @m_goldberg  $Version: 10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit). Quit kernel means to go to Evaluation->Quit kernel->local.   After I restart it the usage is normal (0-1%). The problem usually starts after more demanding calculations but I don't have an exact sequence of how to get to this issue. Nonetheless, it happens almost all the time. It does not occur if I open a notbeook and do nothing else and niether it happens spontaneously after a period of inactivity.

Comment: I also often experience similar problem: after quitting the Kernel and closing all Notebooks the FrontEnd is still takes 50% of CPU on my 2-core laptop. OS Win7 x64, MMa 10.0.0.

Comment: Is this an 8-core / 8-thread processor? I would assume that this is the case and that means the front end is eating up its entire core/thread. I can't tell you why, but confirming the number of cores/threads might be useful to someone who knows more than I do.

Comment: @Kellen It's Intel i7 3820qm so 4 cores/8threads, 2.7GHz and 8MB cache

Comment: So that explains why it's maxing out 1/8 of the total CPU. Or rather, it doesn't explain why, but it explains why the quantity is 1/8 (12.5~13%) and not some other percent.